# search an OWL ontology for individuals with data properties that contains a specific term using sparql

Tags: sparql, owl

I have a complex and huge ontology that i would like to search for individuals that has a data property assertions that contains a specific term through SPARQL. The ontology is OWL but RDF/XML formated.

Comment: And what is the question now?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to be more specific in your question and offer a code/data sample of some sort. Have you tried using a [regex filter](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/DataAccess/rq23/#funcex-regex)? It sounds like this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever SPARQL engine you are using will read the text serialization (RDF/XML, Turtle, JSON-LD) and convert to the engine's internal RDF graph representation.  That there is OWL vocabulary included is irrelevant from SPARQL's perspective - OWL is represented in RDF,

As an more specific example, let's say you're looking for all movies with the word "Silence".  The SPARQL query would look like:

```
SELECT ?movie
WHERE {
  ?movie :hasTitle ?title .
  FILTER regex(?title, "Silence")
}
```

To also get the classes that ?movie belongs to, use the following:

```
SELECT ?movie ?class
WHERE {
  ?movie :hasTitle ?title .
  ?movie a ?class .
  FILTER regex(?title, "Silence")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @scotthenninger, thats a grate and useful answer but i would love it if it could return the parent class of that specific individual......

Comment: The class(es) the individual belongs to?  I edited the answer to include that.